# Angular2 map json to object

Tags: angular

I have a java rest service that returns the following json:

Json Output

```
 {
    "description": "Temperature Sensor",
    "symbol": "°C",
    "name": "degree celsius",
    "maxMeasure": {
        "quantity": 12.8,
        "name": "degree celsius",
        "symbol": "°C",
        "dateTime": "2018-03-15T12:38:23"
    },
    "measure": {
        "quantity": 11.1,
        "name": "degree celsius",
        "symbol": "°C",
        "dateTime": "2018-03-15T18:34:27"
    },
    "minMeasue": {
        "quantity": 5.8,
        "name": "degree celsius",
        "symbol": "°C",
        "dateTime": "2018-03-15T04:09:24"
    },
    "conversionFactor": 1
}
```

through this angular service i call the endpoint :

SensorService.ts

```
getSensor(sensorId: string): Observable<Sensor> {
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('token', 'token');
      headers.append('sensorId', sensorId);
      headers.append('unitMeasureId', '1');
      const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      return this._http.get(this._sensorurl, options)
        .map(data => <Sensor> data.json())
        .do(data => console.log(data));
   }
```

and i map the result in this classes:

Sensor.ts

```
export class Sensor {
  description: string;
  symbol: string;
  name: string;
  maxMeasure: Measure;
  measure: Measure;
  minMeasue: Measure;
  conversionFactor: number;
}
```

Measure.ts

```
export class Measure {
    quantity: string;
    name: string;
    symbol: string;
    dateTime: string;
}
```

with this statement:

sensor.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
      this._sensor.getSensor(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))
          .subscribe(sensor => this.sensor = sensor);
    }
```

the json is correctly read because by the console I can read it, but when it is mapped on the Sensor object give an undefined output.

where is that wrong?

Comment: Where exactly do you get undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when it is mapped on the Sensor object give an undefined output.

You Sensor is **Class**, not an **Interface**:

```
export class Sensor {
  description: string;
  symbol: string;
  name: string;
  maxMeasure: Measure;
  measure: Measure;
  minMeasue: Measure;
  conversionFactor: number;
}
```

Add constructor to **Measure** and **Sensor**, since you are using **Class**:

```
export class Sensor {
  description: string;
  symbol: string;
  name: string;
  maxMeasure: Measure;
  measure: Measure;
  minMeasue: Measure;
  conversionFactor: number;

  // same to Measure class
  constructor(data: Sensor|Object){
   Object.assign(this, data);
   this.assignToClass();
  }

  assignToClass() {
    this.maxMeasure = new Measure(this.maxMeasure);
    this.measure = new Measure(this.measure);
    this.minMeasue = new Measure(this.minMeasue);

  }

}
```

Then, replace in **SensorService.ts**:

```
return this._http.get(this._sensorurl, options)
        .map(data => <Sensor> data.json())
        .do(data => console.log(data));
```

to:

```
 return this._http.get(this._sensorurl, options)
            .map(data => new Sensor(data))
            .do(data => console.log(data));
```

If you use **class**, you should create instance of it by passing object to constructor. Otherwise, if it **Interface** your mapping `<SomeInterface>dataObj` will be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Try `return this._http.get<Sensor>(this._sensorurl, options);`

Answer (score 0):

In service try change :

```
return this._http.get(this._sensorurl, options)
    .map(data => <Sensor> data.json())
    .do(data => console.log(data));
```

to:

```
return this._http.get<Sensor>(this._sensorurl, options)
    .map(data => data.json())
    .do(data => console.log(data));
```

If you use angular >= 4.3.0 change `http: Http` to `http: HttpClient` (`import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common'` - You do not have to parse to JSON. You will be able to delete `.map(data => data.json())`